# Nano suddenly putting in weird characters when I type

Tags: nano, pico

I am using a shell and editing a file in nano (similar to pico). A short while ago, it started doing this thing where if I type:

```
$query = "select" * from topics where id='' ";
```

and then I hit Backspace and try to stick the letter 'a' into the id='' part, it changes it to:

```
$query = "select * from koala_topics where id='a='' ";
```

and the cursor jumps around to a few spaces before. Also if I type

```
print
```

At the start of a new line, and then I think "Oh I should have added a tab" and I go back and try to add a tab, it adds a tab *AND* 2 spaces, and if I put the cursor through the word print, it turns into printnt.

Some other weird things have happened too. I uninstalled nano using yum (which is how I installed it), and then re-installed it, thinking that would get me clean preferences (in case that was the problem) but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Have you or someone close to you spilled coke or some other form of liquid substance on the keyboard?

Comment: Oh yeah I spilled milk all over the keyboard, does that make a difference?

Comment: That is like asking if running your car full speed into a brick wall is bad for your car's mileage.....